# Android oreo ble connection in background

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, rxandroidble, android-8.1-oreo

I need hold ble connection forever. How I can do it for android Oreo with out foreground service ? I need restore application if it was killed of OS. And start application after rebooting . I need every time searching for device and trying to reconnect. Have you any advice ?
Thanks!

Comment: You can't get any guarantees that the app won't be killed if you don't have any foreground service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for a foreground service. Lister for all of BOOT_COMPLETED broadcasts. Pray to Android Gods that it works out.

Comment: :D Thanks . I have same thinks. And thank you and your colleagues for rxAndroidBle library.      P.S.  supporting rxJava2 is cool ;)